# create <mat-error> for each custom validation angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am validating an input, for which I have created 2 custom validators.
what I can't get is to be able to relate each custom validator with a specific mat-error.

I leave my code below, and I appreciate any help

Custom validators:

```js
    ValidateNumbLength(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null  {
    
        let numb = control.value;
        let lengthNumb!: string;
    
        if (numb != null){
          lengthNumb = numb.toString();
        }else {
          return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
    
        if (lengthNumb.length == 1 || lengthNumb.length == 3 ) {
            return null;
        }if (lengthNumb.length == null){
          return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
        else {
          return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
      }
    
      ValidateNnmbValue(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null  {
    
        let numb = control.value;
        let lengthNumb!: string;
    
        if (numb != null){
          lengthNumb = numb.toString();
        }else {
          return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
    
        
        if (numb == 0.5 || numb == 1.0 || numb == 1.5 ){
          return null;
        } if (lengthNumb.length == null){
        return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
        else {
          return  { 'numb invalid!': true };
        }
      }
```

form control:

```js
    this.nominalSizeGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
          
          numb: ['', [ Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]), this.ValidateNumbLength, this.ValidateNnmbValue]],
        });
```

```html
    <mat-error *ngIf="(nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.touched || nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.dirty) && nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.invalid && nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.hasError('ValidateCoolingTomsLength')">
          Cooling tons must be 1 or 3 characters.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.invalid">
          You have entered an incorrect value.
    </mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you return with your validator is the name of the error that the input will have. In your case they key is `'numb invalid!'` for all cases. So to check for these errors it's:

```js
nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.hasError('numb invalid!')
```

If you want different messages for different cases, you need to rename the errors:

```js
ValidateNumbLength(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null  {
        let numb = control.value;
        if (!numb) return { numbIsFalsey : true };
        const lengthNumb = numb.toString();
        if (lengthNumb.length === 1 || lengthNumb.length === 3 ) {
            return null;
        else {
          return  { wrongLength: true };
        }
      }
```

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.hasError('numbIsFalsey')">
  Please enter a value.
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="nominalSizeGroup.get('numb')?.hasError('wrongLength')">
  Cooling tons must be 1 or 3 characters.
</mat-error>
```

**Just a side note:** you should never use `==` for equality, that only exists for legacy code, `===` is the proper way.